# No export name XYZ found in serverless framework

Tags: yaml, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

```
functions:
  wsConnect:
    handler: src/handlers/wsConnect.handler
    name: ${self:provider.stage}-wsConnect
    environment:
      WS_SERVICE: ${self:provider.stage}-wsService
    events:
      - websocket:
          route: $connect
  wsDisconnect:
    handler: src/handlers/wsDisconnect.handler
    name: ${self:provider.stage}-wsDisconnect
    environment:
      WS_SERVICE: ${self:provider.stage}-wsService
    events:
      - websocket:
          route: $disconnect
  wsDefault:
    handler: src/handlers/wsDefault.handler
    name: ${self:provider.stage}-wsDefault
    events:
      - websocket:
          route: $default
resources:
    Outputs:
        ExportedWebSocketpi:
          Value: !Ref WebsocketsApi # Logical ID
          Export:
            Name: webSocketAPI
        ExportedRestApi:
          Value: !Ref ApiGatewayRestApi # Logical ID
          Export:
            Name: rest-wsAPI
custom:
  importwebSocketAPI:
    Fn::ImportValue: webSocketAPI
```

I have created this WebSocket and tried to deploy it for the first time, It is showing **No export name webSocketAPI** found, custom: tag is executing before output exports the API. How can I do it with DependsOn or is there any other way for doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the required field field for output - [value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html)

Here you may found how to set up [Outputs in serverless framework](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-export-outputs)

Another examples:

```
resources:
    Outputs:
        DBUserName:
            Value: ${self:custom.dbCredentials.DB_USERNAME}
        DBPassword:
            Value: ${self:custom.dbCredentials.DB_PSW}

        RDSClusterID:
            Description: "RDS Cluster"
            Value: { Ref: RDSCluster }

        CognitoUserPoolId:
            Value: ${self:custom.userPool}
```

Comment: Please check out my updated code. even this code giving the same issue. Why because it **custom: TAG** is not waiting for the resource to complete.

Comment: The custom tag reads/imports the value `webSocketAPI` from AWS CloudFormation variables. The `webSocketAPI` is exported from the same stack. Therefore you get kind of circular dependency, you try to read what has not been created. Read directly `WebsocketsApi` within your serverless.yml config, you don't need to export/import the variables.